# OMNET++ 4.2.2 .gdbinit: No such file or directory

Tags: gdb, omnet++

I've got an error ".gdbinit: No such file or directory." when trying to debugging in Omnet++ 4.2.2 in Ubuntu 12.4. It seems that the debugger cannot find ".gdbinit", or the find the one not compatible. So where can I find ".gdbinit" in my PC, or where should I find the right version of it to replace? Any idea would be appreciated!

Danh

---

Hi all, I have alternative solution for my problem and would like to write here for those who need to refer later. Instead of using gdb we can use valgrind. As my understanding, it is pretty good tool to detect bug related to memory allocation. To use valgrind in Omnet, you must make sure to have it installed in your OS (e.g., in Ubuntu, just type sudo apt-get install valgrind). Then in Omnet IDE, simply choose Profile As.. instead of Debug As.. then choose Omnet++Simulation, then trace bugs in valgrind windows. I did find where my bug is by this way. 
Thanks.
Danh

Comment: Does `ls -l ~/.gdbinit` show anything? It sounds like it could be a symbolic link to a file that got moved. Does typing just `gdb` to your shell display any errors?

Comment: @Mark: here are the reports when I type your two commands:  grsst@OBSModules:~$ ls -l ~/.gdbinit
ls: cannot access /home/grsst/.gdbinit: No such file or directory
grsst@OBSModules:~$ gdb
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.

Comment: What command do you type (or click) just before you see the `.gdbinit: No such file or directory` error message?

Comment: In fact, I am working in Omnet++, and tried to run Debug As.. then choose Omnet++Simulation.

Comment: just to provide you with more info: I am using 64-bit Ubuntu 12.4. In Omnet++ there is an custom option that allows to choose .gdbinit, but I don't know where the current .gdbinit is, and how can I update it to another version to make a trial.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. It could be that either the OMNeT++ IDE itself is producing that error message, or it is telling gdb to read in a .gdbinit file that doesn't exist. Someone here who's familiar with that IDE should be able to help. gdb normally is silent when there's no .gdbinit file, since it's optional.

Comment: Hi all, I have alternative solution for my problem and would like to write here for those who need to refer later. Instead of using gdb we can use valgrind. As my understanding, it is pretty good tool to detect bug related to memory allocation. To use valgrind in Omnet, you must make sure to have it installed in your OS (e.g., in Ubuntu, just type sudo apt-get install valgrind). Then in Omnet IDE, simply choose Profile As.. instead of Debug As.. then choose Omnet++Simulation, then trace bugs in valgrind windows. I did find where my bug is by this way. Thanks.